# UK visa with past conviction

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, deception, criminal-records

I recently applied for a UK visa but was denied based on the fact that I did not declare a criminal conviction of 1989. There was no jail term, but I was given 50 hours of community service and a fine of GBP230. I didn't declare because it took place long ago and I felt, since no jail term, it wasn't necessary. I have since requested for a UK Police record which I have now.

I want to apply again to attend a friend daughter's wedding. What are my chances?

Comment: Do a search on here for "UK Visa" and "deception". You'll see the chance you stand.

Comment: You'd need a really good reason for not declaring that conviction. However, the reason you have provided here simply isn't going to work, unfortunately.

Comment: The title is a little misleading. The problem is not the past conviction, but the failure to list it on the application.

Comment: What did your refusal letter say about future applications?

Comment: Future Applications: Any Future UK visa Applications you make will be considered on their individual merits, however you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances of your application change. In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

Comment: Any further help with suggestions